# When and why did humans start disliking the way we naturally smell?

Tags: human-biology, senses, olfaction, nose, chemical-communication

Like many animals, humans produce a myriad of scents from [sweating](http://www.berkeley.edu/news/media/releases/2007/02/06_sweat.shtml), bacteria, [possibly pheromones](http://www.ted.com/talks/tristram_wyatt_the_smelly_mystery_of_the_human_pheromone?language=en), etc. Many of these scents are used throughout the animal kingdom for mate choice, recognition of individuals, or signifying presence or territory.

I know that humans subconsciously react to some scent cues (see [here](http://evolution.anthro.univie.ac.at/institutes/urbanethology/resources/articles/articles/publications/226-2005-humanpheromones-sexattraction.pdf), [here](http://faculty.wcas.northwestern.edu/~paller/PsychSci07.pdf), or [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4345842/pdf/elife05154.pdf) for examples), but it seems many humans find natural human scent to, well, *smell*. Interestingly, this [article](http://news.discovery.com/human/human-sweat-smell-mosquito-110223.htm) suggests that humans' smell is *worse* than that of other animals.

My question is: **if these scents hold so much information, how/why did humans develop an aversion to the natural scent of other humans?**

Further, ***when* did this occur?** -- recently or long ago in human culture? I know Egyptians made perfumes thousands of years ago, so this is not a fully recent trend. Perhaps someone could comment on the ubiquitousness of this aversion across modern cultures as well.

Comment: I don't believe this question is opinion based. It is fairly well known and demonstrated in my links (and countless other sources) that people find the body odor of others repugnant at times. The question asks for a historical /evolutionary explanation of why that is. That falls well in the range of accepted questions on this SE site. I feel those that voted to close nitpicked details in my text instead of focusing on the actual question, which is valid here.

Comment: I think that the "humans produce pheromones" part is problematic, you might want to remove that. To my knowledge no human pheromone (a specific molecule) has ever been identified, although some behavioral studies have suggested that there is information in smell. But this is really not so relevant to the question in the title anyway, so you could take out this part. Just the question of why our "natural" odor is repugnant to us is interesting in itself, regardless of what "information" it might carry,

Comment: @Roland I've modified this portion. I've now included the phrase "possibly pheromones" and included a link to a TED talk by one of the world's experts on the subject, Tristram Wyatt, who gives a good summary of the pheromone subject (which I believe is pertinent to this question). Please vote to reopen if you see no additional issues with this question.

Comment: I don't think there is a general aversion against other people smells. In fact, smells seem to me to be a very important part of a romantic relationship.

Comment: @Remi.b but there *is* a general aversion: that's ultimately why the deodorant industry exists (and arguably why perfumes and soaps exist as well...).  For further discussion, for example, see [here](https://theweek.com/articles/614722/brief-history-body-odor)

Comment: I think it's not human smell per se, just sweat. Probably because of association with bad hygiene and therefore risk of infection as you mention yourself - disgust as part of the behavioural immune system. I'd guess we gave up on smell in favour of social cognition and language, which we use for some social functions for which other animals use smells. So it wouldn't surprise that we find a different use for smell.

Comment: Hunting... if you smell bad, animals smell you better.  Go take bath.  Also, clean people get less diseases, go take bath.  Etc.  Therefore, smelly people are gross, weak hunters who get people sick.  Also, if you like smelling bad, you die more.